# Fetching artifacts from Nexus to Rundeck

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, nexus, continuous-deployment, rundeck

I'm creating a Rundeck job which will be used to rollback an application. My .jar files are stored in a Nexus repository and I would like to add an option to Rundeck where I can choose a .jar version from Nexus and then run the rollback job on this.

I have tried using this plugin: https://github.com/nongfenqi/nexus3-rundeck-plugin, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I am logged in to Nexus I can access the JSON file listing the artifacts from my browser, but when I am logged off the JSON file is empty, even if the Nexus server is running.

When adding the JSON URL as a remote URL option in Rundeck like the picture below, I get no option to choose from when running the job, even if I am logged in to Nexus, as shown by picture number 2. Is there a way to pass user credentials with options, or any other workaround for this?

[image: Remote URL to JSON file]
[image: Empty options list]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install Apache / HTTPD locally on your rundeck server and use a CGI script for this.

1. Write a CGI script that queries your Nexus3 service for versions available on the jar file, and echo the results in JSON format.
2. Place the script in /var/www/cgi-bin/ with executable bit enabled. You can test it like so:

   curl 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/script-name.py'
3. In your job you can configure your remote URL accordingly.

I find using local CGI script to be much more reliable and flexible. You can also handle any authentication requirements there.